# MS Excel, Consolidating list of cells

Tags: excel

Thanks for the help, in advance.

I have a list of cells (say in Col A)

```
A1 - Albania; A2 - Australia; A3- #Value!; A4 - Angola; A5 - #Value!
```

I want to consolidate the list in Col.A into another column B, but without any errors "#Value!"; like this

```
B1 - Albania; B2 - Australia; B3 - Angola
```

How do I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX/AGGEGATE:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$5)/(NOT(ISERROR($A$1:$A$5))),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I used this formula, but it is skipping certain cells with non-error values. Does it matter if the strings (in this case countries in col A) are derived from a formula?

Comment: No, what exactly is the formula you are using?

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX($AA$3:$AA$237,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($AA$3:$AA$237)/(NOT(ISERROR($AA$1:$AA$237))),ROW(1:1))),"") My data is between cells AA3 and AA237

Comment: just changed the formula to =IFERROR(INDEX($AA$3:$AA$237,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($AA$3:$AA$237)/(NOT(ISERROR($AA$1:$AA$237))),ROW(3:3))),"") since data starts from row 3; still has gaps

Comment: You need to refer to the full column in the INDEX, instead of `...INDEX($AA$3:$AA$237...` use `...INDEX($AA:$AA$...`

Comment: And in the first formula it needs to stay as `ROW(1:1)` it will adjust appropriately as you drag it down. @Suneesh

Comment: I was just checking the formula - while it is aggregating most of the values - it is skipping a few of them randomly. @Scott

Comment: Example - when the values in columns was                                                   

          Belgium
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
Bhutan
Bolivia
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
Bulgaria
Burkina Faso
#VALUE!
#VALUE!
Cabo Verde
                                                                                                                                                 .      The aggregation skipped Bhutan and Bulgaria

Comment: Be sure you have made the references absolute and they refer to the whole range.